# application that uses xforwarding fails unless I use xhost +localhost

Tags: linux, centos, xorg

I'm connected to a remote system over nomachine enterprise. We use an internal application that I believe is essentially xforwarded from another machine as I run it - it runs there, and outputs the information to me graphically.

When we try to run it, we get the error

```
xNo protocol specified
Jul 06 03:47:03 FATAL   Tk init failure: couldn't connect to display ":1004.0"
```

running `xhosts +localhost` lets me run that application, but [there's vague posts that its dangerous](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4194).

What's the *right* way to allow this?

We're running centos 6.5, and gnome 2.28.2 and nomachine enterprise. I'm running as a regular user and the application works fine locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, this message comes up when you are logged in as an un-authorized-X-server-user. This might happen, for instance, when one tries to do an `su`.

In those cases, the correct procedure is to access the `.Xauthority` file of the real user of the X server. For instance, on my laptop, in order to allow access to the X-server when I become `su`, I have created a symbolic link, `/root/.Xauthority`, to `/home/myname/.Xauthority`.

The normal procedure is to display the MIT magic cookie (which is contained in `.Xauthority` in a format unsuitable for text display) as

```
   $ xauth list $DISPLAY
    rasal/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  fdc693bdad69a20665771a695cdde589
```

and then, as the new user to be empowered, to give the following command:

```
   $  xauth add rasal/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  fdc693bdad69a20665771a695cdde589
```

The problem occurs most often on Debian and derivatives, because here the environment variable `XAUTHORITY` is not set. You should definitely try to set it,

```
   export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
```

. However, if other users are involved (I have never run NoMachine, but many Nix applications create *ad hoc* users) you may want to make it permanent for all users: then you can edit `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment`. remember to point it to an existing user's MIT magic cookie file, though!

Comment: ooh. Nomachine runs as its own user. And this application runs as a third user. I will not shed tears when we replace this with the new, improved, web based replacement.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Did this fully solve your problem, or did this just point you in the right direction?

Comment: Its the right way to do it, from what I've seen. Didn't work for my specific situation because nx is strange.

Comment: I'd add that the reason you should not do this is that its trivial to spoof a hostname, so someone else can pretend to be you.